# Schedule a job on specific git branch using GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a workflow file in mainline. I have code in other branch which I will not be merging into mainline.
I am looking to schedule a GHA job to run code from my specific job.

```
name: On_premise
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '40 10 * * 1-5'
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
```

Answer (score 1):

[`on`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on) is for triggering the workflow when an event happens. Events such as [`push`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore) and [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore) take a `branches` option so they only fire when a push or PR happens on particular branches.

[`on.schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) triggers by time, a `branches` option makes no sense.

Instead, have your workflow [switch to the branch of your choosing](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout#Checkout-a-different-branch).

```
name: On_premise
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '40 10 * * 1-5'

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with: 
          ref: somebranch
      - run: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```